# jQuery hover show panel

Tags: jquery

It's pretty simple I'm sure but bugging me. I have the following code to slide a panel up when hovering on a link lower down, the issue I have is the panel slides back down when I move onto it (as I have moved off the trigger)

```
$('#menu-item-245').hover(
     function() {

        var captionHeight = $('.fullTimeSection').height(); 
        captionHeight = parseInt(captionHeight, 10);
        var topHeight = 190 - captionHeight;
        var topHeight =+ topHeight + 'px';

        $('.fullTimeSection').stop().animate(
        {
            top: topHeight

        },
        500
        ); 
     },
     function() {
         $('.fullTimeSection').animate(
        {
            top: '190px'

        },
        500
        );
     }
  );
```

HTML is basically this:

```
<div id="panelHolder">

     <div class="fullTimeSection">
        Slide panel content here...
     </div>

   </div>

   <ul>
     <li id="#menu-item-245"><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
     <li><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
     <li><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show your HTML code, please. It will be better if you show your problem in FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/ (more comfortable to help you as for me)

Comment: Hi melvis, original edited with HTML

Comment: Here is my quick jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QE67u/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your fiddle sample. See the code below to solve your problem:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="panelHolder">
        <div class="panel" id="fullTimeSection">Content 1!</div>    
        <div class="panel" id="sixthFormSection">Content 2!</div>    
        <div class="panel" id="partTimeSection">Content 3!</div>
    </div>    

    <nav role="category-navigation" id="catNav">
        <ul id="menu-sections" class="section-menu">
            <li class="menu-item" data-id="fullTimeSection"><a href="#">Full Time</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" data-id="sixthFormSection"><a href="#">Sixth Form</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" data-id="partTimeSection"><a href="#">Part TIme</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>     
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {width:100%; padding:0; position:relative; height:250px; margin-top:250px;}
#catNav ul {list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
#catNav li {width:100px; display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;}

#panelHolder {position:absolute; top:-190px; width:100%; height:190px; overflow:hidden;}

.panel{width:94%; height:170px; padding:10px 3%; color:white; position:absolute; top:190px;}

.panel#fullTimeSection {background:#870057;}
.panel#sixthFormSection {background:#232323;}
.panel#partTimeSection { background:#555555;}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.menu-item').hover(
     function() {
         var panel = $('#' + $(this).data('id'));
         var captionHeight = panel.height();
         captionHeight = parseInt(captionHeight, 10);
         var topHeight = 190 - captionHeight;
         var topHeight =+ topHeight + 'px';
         panel.stop().animate({ top: topHeight }, 500); 
     },
     function() {
         $('#' + $(this).data('id')).animate({ top: '190px' }, 500);
     }
  );
```

**And FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/QE67u/10/

I hope this is exactly what you wanted.

**EDIT**

I think you can just hold menu panel until you don't choose other menu block. See example code below and FIDDLE, of course:

```
$('.menu-item').hover(
     function() {
         $('.panel').animate({ top: '190px' }, 500);

         var panel = $('#' + $(this).data('id'));
         var captionHeight = panel.height();
         captionHeight = parseInt(captionHeight, 10);
         var topHeight = 190 - captionHeight;
         var topHeight =+ topHeight + 'px';
         panel.stop().animate({ top: topHeight }, 500); 
     }
  );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QE67u/14/

Comment: Hi melvas, thanks so much for your help. Yes its nearly there but the last thing I need is for the panel that has slid up to stay up when the user places their cursor inside it, its like a mega menu but also with other content. i know the usual way would be to make them part of each li, that way they would naturally stay up but I cant and they have to be separate.  Thanks

Comment: Hi melvas, unfortunately that cant work, if you have a go once you have any block slid up its impossible to remove them, if you move to the next one that just stays open. It definitely needs to close either by moving the cursor off the link, or by moving it off the panel, or by placing the cursor over the next link item. Sorry